# SignalR hubconnection failed while using AppCenter key (UWP Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, signalr, visual-studio-app-center

I created a cross platform application using signalr.
The RTC was working fine. Recently I created a new app version released in which I integrated AppCenter.
The application has been tested on the dev computer with the packages used to publiqh the application on the partner center. The hub was able to connect.
Unfortunately, the application from the store was not able to connect to the hub.
My setup:

1. Signalr hosted locally (not in azure)
2. Bug related on all windows version (arm, x86, x64)
3. Appcenter.start key is setup only when crashes happen, and unset after (string when not filled according to Appcenter configuration)
4. The only difference with the previous version is that AppCenter.start was activated only if the system was android.
5. The signalR soes not have any reference to the key

Does someone can help me understand where I am missing something in the setup?
Thanks in advance.